# Who can help me write a regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to find multi-line text the beginning of the string `cc` to `kk` end, and must include the string `c3` and `c4`, but can not include the string `dd` or `ee`, the following test data:

```
t1 b1 cc
c3 c4 z1
t3 dd kk

t4 b2 cc
c4 c3 z2
t6 ee kk

t7 b3 cc
c3 c4 z3
t9 ff kk

t7 b3 cc
c4 c3 z3
t9 ff kk
```

Expected results and only:

```
cc
c3 c4 z3
t9 ff kk

cc
c4 c3 z3
t9 ff kk
```

I wrote a regular expression(C#), but this result is not expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the regex engine to check for the condition before matching each single character.

```
@"(?s)\bcc\b(?:(?!dd|ee).)*?\bkk\b"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zM0pD2/1)

`(?:(?!dd|ee).)*?` should match any character but not of `dd` or `ee` , zero or more times (*non-greedily*).
\

Update:

```
(?s)\bcc\b(?:(?!\bdd\b|\bee\b).)*?\bc3\b(?:(?!\bdd\b|\bee\b).)*?\bkk\b
```

Comment: @MikeMB added a bit. You may see the explanation of each regex pattern at the right side of the demo link I attached. If there any doubts on that explanation, feel free to ask me..

Comment: for more accuracy, `@"(?s)\bcc\b(?:(?!\b(?:dd|ee)\b).)*?\bkk\b"`

Comment: sorry, I have updated the question. could you please help me again?

Comment: then replace `3` with `\d` (matches any digit char) like `(?s)\bcc\b(?:(?!\bdd\b|\bee\b).)*?\bc\d\b(?:(?!\bdd\b|\bee\b).)*?\bkk\b`

Comment: if you want c3 and c4 then replace `\d` with `[34]`

Comment: c3 and c4 is just an identifier, it is actually a string, such as: bug, exception etc..

Comment: thank you again, I think it should be right, but it is too cumbersome : (?s)cc(?:(?!dd|ee).)*?(?:(?:c3).*?(?:c4)|(?:c4).*?(?:c3))(?:(?!dd|ee).)*?kk

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cc(?:\s(?!dd|ee)\w{2})*\skk
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE3kR1/1)

**Explanation:**
`(?: … )`: Non-capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bU9dN1/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`(?!…)`: Negative lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bI9fA5/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`\w`: "word character": ASCII letter, digit or underscore [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ2lG4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)

`(?!dd|ee)\w{2}` 2 character but `dd` or `ee` [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qF2wI9/1)